# GKR storetype not working in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jks

I have a keystore generated with GNU/JAVA and its storetype is GKR.
Now the tomcat is not supporting GKR type keystore. Is there any way to rum GKR storetype in tomcat? 
Or any way to convert GKR storetype to JKS.

Following is the exception encountered at tomcat:

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-80
Dec 14, 2011 10:25:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory getStore
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type gkr with path /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/CSR/music543213_keystore due to gkr not found
java.security.KeyStoreException: gkr not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:384)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:571)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:430)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: gkr KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:142)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:659)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:584)
    ... 21 more
Dec 14, 2011 10:25:40 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not Apache Tomcat that doesn't support the GKR type, it's the JVM (visibly Sun/Oracle) with which you're running it that doesn't support this type.

If you want to use the Oracle/Sun JRE, you'll need to convert your keystore into one of its supported formats (e.g. JKS), or to find a way to use the GNU security provider with that JRE.